# Disable Angular HttpInterceptor for some call

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I have an angular application with an HttpInterceptor that catch the http errors to show some dialog, common to all my application.

I would like to disable the interceptor for some specific calls but I prefer to disable the default behaviour where i call the http, instead of write an exception into the interceptor.
Anyone have found this problem?

I can be more specific with an example, if needed.

Regards

Davide

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55522320/angular-interceptor-exclude-specific-urls/55522787#55522787

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `HttpBackend` to do this.

**Description:** When injected, HttpBackend dispatches requests directly to the backend, without going through the interceptor chain.

**Using:** You can use same like `HttpClient`by import it from `@angular/common/http`

Example:

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpBackend } from '@angular/common/http';

...

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpHelperService {

  private httpClient: HttpClient;

  constructor( httpBackend: HttpBackend) { 
     this.httpClient = new HttpClient(httpBackend);
  }

  // use like normal with HttpClient. However, should name it carefully to separate which http request go throught interceptor and which is not
  put(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.put(
      `${this.URL}${path}`,
      JSON.stringify(body)
    ).pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
  }

....
```

ref: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpBackend

Comment: For Angular version below 12, this is useful, but in my case by using HttpBackend, I was getting CORS error. So i followed the approach of setting headers and then putting a condition in intercepter, as explained in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55522787/14069524

Comment: this isn't what user has asked, please update answer  to help inquiry.

Answer (score 42):

With **Angular 12**, it's possible now to include some metadata (with `HttpContext`) in your call that can be used within the interceptor to make decisions (or anything you want really).

**Example**

Your interceptor:

```js
export const BYPASS_LOG = new HttpContextToken(() => false);

export class MyLogInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (req.context.get(BYPASS_LOG) === true)
      return next.handle(req);

    console.log(`req to ${req.url}`);

    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

Your service:

```js
httpClient.get('https://example.com/', { context: new HttpContext().set(BYPASS_LOG, true) });
```

You can checkout angular docs for more information:

- [Intercepting requests and responses](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses)
- [Passing metadata to interceptors](https://angular.io/guide/http#passing-metadata-to-interceptors)

Comment: Great Job ! TnQ

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a small service class to do this.
The service just needs to toggle a flag to indicate whether the interceptor should run, and the interceptor class can check the flag before running.

```
@Injectable()
export class InterceptorOverrideService {

disableInterceptor = false;

constructor() { }

disable() {
   this.disableInterceptor = true;        
}

enable() {
  this.disableInterceptor = false;
}
}
```

And the Interceptor class:

```
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

private count = 0;

constructor(private overrideService: InterceptorOverrideService) { }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const methods = ['POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'];
    if (methods.indexOf(req.method) === -1 || this.overrideService.disableInterceptor) {
        return next.handle(req);
    }

    //Your Code here

    return next.handle(req).pipe(finalize(() => { //finalize is called for either success or error responses            
    }));
}
}
```

Comment: I like this idea, but how do you toggle the interceptor in your InterceptorOverrideService?