# How to use conditional interceptor between custom Interceptor and Msal Interceptor based on Request Uri in Angular

Tags: angular, interceptor, azure-ad-msal

I have implemented @azure/msal-angular 2.0 in my angular 11 project.
I have used 2 Apis in this project.
Few APis require custom interceptor (AuthInterceptor) and few require MsalInterceptor by msal.js.
Both APIs can only use one Interceptor at a time else the request fails.
I want to know how to customize both MsalInterceptor and CustomInterceptor in a single interceptor.

This is my app.module.ts file (Here either I want to remove msalinterceptor and customize it in AuthInterceptor  OR I want to keep both interceptors here and use it conditionally based on request URI)

```
  providers: [
{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: AuthInterceptor,
  multi: true
},
{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: MsalInterceptor,
  multi: true
},  
{
  provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
  useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory
},
{
  provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
  useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory
},
{
  provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
  useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory
},
MsalService,
MsalGuard,
MsalBroadcastService
```

],

This is how i am trying to customize AuthInterceptor by using MsalInterceptor in this file.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {      
    if (req.url.indexOf(this.APIOne) !== -1) {

      // I want to use USE MSALInterceptor Here. but it is not working.

              const scopesInformation = {
                        scopes: [
                             'mail.send'
                        ],
                     };
                       
                    this.auth.instance.acquireTokenSilent(scopesInformation).then(tokenResponse => {
                             debugger;
                             req = req.clone({
                                 setHeaders: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + tokenResponse.accessToken }
                            });
                         });
                     
    } else
        if (req.url.indexOf(this.APITwo) !== -1) {
          // This is my custom interceptor which does not require MsalInterceptor Token.
            this.token = localStorage.getItem('APITwoToken');
            const authReq = req.clone({
                headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
                   'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
                    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
                    'Expires': 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT'
                }), setHeaders: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.token }
            })
            req = authReq;
        }

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
        tap(
            event => this.handleResponse(req, event),
            error => this.handleError(req, error)
        )
    );
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a temporary solution. Just moved MSALInterceptor above the AuthInterceptor.
Don't know if its a good solution, but somehow this worked.

```
{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: MsalInterceptor,
  multi: true
},
{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: AuthInterceptor,
  multi: true
},
```

Comment: why not use some like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55522320/angular-interceptor-exclude-specific-urls/55522787#55522787? indicate in headers what kind of "interceptor" you need (really you hss an unique interceptor that check in "headers" is has a property or not)

Comment: this is a very nice answer, this might be the one I am looking for, thank you very much @Eliseo