# How to call API service inside Interceptors Angular

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient-interceptors

I am trying to call API service inside the interceptor.

**My API service code:**

```
showAcknowledgement() {
    this.noticeService.getNotice(ConstUrls.NoticeManagement.GetUserNotice).subscribe((data: any) => {
      data.data.filter((res: any) => {
      if (data.isSuccessful === true) {
        this.noticeText = res.noticeText
        }
      } else if (data.isSuccessful === false) {
        this.message = [{ field: "", message: data.message[0].message }];
        this.objError = this.message;
        this.showError = true;
        window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
      }
    })
    }, (error) => {
      this.message = [{ field: "", message: "error" }];
      this.objError = this.message;
      this.showError = true;
      window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
    });
  }
```

**My Interceptor Code:**

```
  public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
        tap((resp) => {
            if (resp instanceof HttpResponse && resp.body.isNotificationAvailable) {
              // I need to call my service API
            }
        })
    );
  }
```

If I call API inside Interceptor its hitting multiple times.

Comment: You can directly inject your service(that container `showAcknowledgement()` method in interceptor and call the API.

Comment: Because your interceptor is Http Interceptor and based on Interceptor's logic it get called on every request. You should change your app logic

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55522320/angular-interceptor-exclude-specific-urls/55522787#55522787

Comment: @JsNgian: If I call the method directly also API is hitting infinite times

Comment: @HassanGhasemi Can you please guide me some other logic

Comment: exactly what do you want to do?

Comment: I have fixed this issue by removing the "isNotificationAvailable" property in particular API. Thanks to all who replied.