# Angular: Http Interceptor for some requests

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors

I have an Angular 15 app, which sends quite a bunch of requests.
Most of the requests need Authorization with a Bearer token. Therefore I use an `HttpInterceptor`.

But, there are some requests, which don't need Authorization (i.e. google maps API). However, everyone of my requests has Authorization now, due to the `HttpInterceptor`.

How do I work around this?

Comment: You can add an extra parameter to your request / header and check in your interceptor if its there. Depending on that you add the token or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answers - I'll implement the context solution, which looks good!

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are three ways :

- you create an array constant which contains the URLS of the links that can bypass the interceptor and skip the token appending for these links only
- you can add a special header for the request who don't need a token , check if it's in the header in the interceptor , if it's there remove it and don't add your token , if not just trigger the appending

in plus , it's a duplicate of [Angular interceptor exclude specific urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55522320/angular-interceptor-exclude-specific-urls) , you'll find more answer there .